# WPF - can I prevent word-wrap on a phrase within a wrapping TextBlock?

Tags: wpf

Does WPF allow me to specify a section of text that should not be split up?

In my case, I have a URL as part of the text in a paragraph.  I want word-wrapping, but I *don't* want it to split up that URL.

That is to say, this is ok:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the
http://lazydog.example.com/blah/monkey/apple/carburetor again
and again and again.
```

but this is *not* ok:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the http://lazydog.example.com/
blah/monkey/apple/carburetor again and again and again.
```

Can I somehow mark that URL (or any phrase) as not-splittable in WPF?

Comment: The simplest approach would be to wrap the link in its own non-wrapping `TextBlock` element.

Comment: Why don't you put that as an *answer*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems obvious in retrospect:

Simply put my non-word-wrapped part in a nested 'TextBlock' with word-wrap disabled.